# JavaScript Code executing twice outside of functions

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, d3.js

I am developing a site locally using D3 JS. When I do anything  outside of any function it is happening twice, no matter where it is within the code. Example:

```
console.log("2x");

Console output is:
2x
2x
```

However if the code is inside any of the functions it only prints once. I noticed that next to the logs there is two different locations for their origin

```
Console output
2x                                   site.js:3
2x                                   site.js?v=twO2e-dF40DXz0Jm_X753ZBfaW8vwQs0ht7UrLyed5E:3
```

Inside a function the logs only originate from the longer string version. This affects any code outside a function, it seems to run twice...I've included the full code for reference if required.

I have found many similarly titled or tagged questions but all of them were due to the logging occurring in a loop or otherwise, I couldn't find any where it happened in the base code.

EDIT: My code does have two console.logs but that results in 4 prints in that case sorry for being unclear on that.

JavaScript

```
//Azibuda

console.log("2x");

//Get the SVG element
var svg = d3.select("svg");

var width = 960, height = 600;
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);

var link = svg.append("g").selectAll(".link");
var node = svg.append("g").selectAll(".node");
var label = svg.append("g").selectAll(".label");

//Begin the force simulation
var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function (d) { return d.id; }).distance(50).strength(0.3))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-15))
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

//Highlight variables
var highlight_color = "blue";
var tHighlight = 0.05;

var config;

var linkedByIndex = {};
var linksAsString = {};

//Get the data
d3.json("/../../data.json", function (data) {

    config = data;
    if (!localStorage.graph)
    {
        localStorage.graph = JSON.stringify(data);
    }
    update();

});

function update() {

    console.log(localStorage.graph);

    //Create an array of source,target containing all links
    config.links.forEach(function (d) {
        linkedByIndex[d.source + "," + d.target] = true;
        linkedByIndex[d.target + "," + d.source] = true;

        //linksAsString[d.index] = d.source + "," + d.target;
    });

    var nodesAsString = {};
    config.nodes.forEach(function (d) {
        nodesAsString[d.index] = d.id + "," + d.radius;
    });

    //Draw links
    link = link.data(config.links);
    link.exit().remove();
    link = link.enter().append("line")
            .attr("class", "link")
            .attr("stroke-width", 2)
            .attr("stroke", "#888")
            //.attr("opacity", function (d) { if (d.target.radius > 7) { return 1 }; return 0; })
            .merge(link);         


    node = node.data(config.nodes);
    node.exit().remove();
    node = node.enter().append("circle")
            .attr("class", "node")
            .attr("r", function(d) { return d.radius; })
            .attr("fill", function (d) { return color(d.id); })
            .attr("stroke", "black")
        //  .attr("pointer-events", function (d) { if (d.radius <= 7) { return "none"; } return "visibleAll"; })
        //  .attr("opacity", function (d) { if (d.radius <= 7) { return 0; } return 1; })
            .call(d3.drag()
            .on("start", dragstarted)
            .on("drag", dragged)
            .on("end", dragended))
            .on("mouseover", mouseOver)
            .on("mouseout", mouseOut)
            .merge(node);

    label = label.data(config.nodes);
    label.exit().remove();
    label = label.enter().append("text")
            .attr("class", "label")
            .attr("dx", function (d) { return d.radius * 1.25; })
            .attr("dy", ".35em")
            .attr("opacity", function (d) { if (d.radius <= 7) { return 0; } return 1; })
            .attr("font-weight", "normal")
            .style("font-size", 10)
            .text(function (d) { return d.id; })
            .merge(label);

    //Add nodes to simulation
    simulation
        .nodes(config.nodes)
        .on("tick", ticked);

    //Add links to simulation
    simulation.force("link")
        .links(config.links);

    simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
}

//Animating by ticks function
function ticked() {
    node
        .attr("cx", function (d) { return d.x = Math.max(d.radius, Math.min(width - d.radius, d.x)); })
        .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.y = Math.max(d.radius, Math.min(height - d.radius, d.y)); });
    link
        .attr("x1", function (d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function (d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function (d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function (d) { return d.target.y; });
    label
        .attr("x", function (d) { return d.x = Math.max(d.radius, Math.min(width - d.radius, d.x)); })
        .attr("y", function (d) { return d.y = Math.max(d.radius, Math.min(height - d.radius, d.y)); });
}

//Using above array, check if two nodes are linked
function isConnected(node1, node2) {
    return linkedByIndex[node1.id + "," + node2.id] || node1.index == node2.index;
}


//Highlight a node
function setHighlight(d) {
    svg.style("cursor", "pointer");

    //Set highlighted stroke around the current node, text and its links
    node.style("stroke", function (tNode) {
        return isConnected(d, tNode) ? highlight_color : "black";
    });

    label.style("font-weight", function (tNode) {
        return isConnected(d, tNode) ? "bold" : "normal";
    });

    link.style("stroke", function (tNode) {
        return tNode.source.index == d.index || tNode.target.index == d.index ? highlight_color : "#888";
    });
}

//Drag/mousedown on a node
function dragstarted(d) {
    if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
    d.fx = d.x;
    d.fy = d.y;
}

//Dragging a node
function dragged(d) {
    d.fx = d3.event.x;
    d.fy = d3.event.y;

    //Highlight/focus on held down node
    setFocus(d);
    setHighlight(d);
}

//End drag/mouseup on a node
function dragended(d) {
    if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
    d.fx = null;
    d.fy = null;
}

//Mouse over on a node
function mouseOver(d) {
    setFocus(d);
    setHighlight(d);
}

//Mouse off of a node
function mouseOut(d) {
    unFocus(d);
    highlightOff();
}

//Turning off highlight
function highlightOff() {
    svg.style("cursor", "default");

    //Set node attributes back to normal
    node.style("stroke", "black");
    label.style("font-weight", "normal");
    link.style("stroke", "#888");
}

//Focus on a node
function setFocus(d) {
    //Set opacity of all non-connected nodes and their elements (text/links) to faded
    node.style("opacity", function (tNode) {
        return isConnected(d, tNode) ? 1 : tHighlight;
    });

    label.style("opacity", function (tNode) {
        return isConnected(d, tNode) ? 1 : tHighlight;
    });

    link.style("opacity", function (tNode) {
        return tNode.source.index == d.index || tNode.target.index == d.index ? 1 : tHighlight;
    });
}

//Unfocus on a node (reset all to normal)
function unFocus(d) {
    //node.style("opacity", function (d) { if (d.radius <= 7) { return 0; } return 1; });
    //node.style("pointer-events", function (d) { if (d.radius <= 7) { return "none"; } return "visibleAll"; })
    node.style("opacity", 1);
    label.style("opacity", function (d) { if (d.radius <= 7) { return 0; } return 1; });
    //link.style("opacity", function (d) { if (d.target.radius > 7) { return 1 }; return 0; });
    link.style("opacity", 1);
}

function updateR()
{
    console.log(config.nodes[2]);
    config.nodes.splice(2, 1);
    update();
}

var temp = JSON.parse(localStorage.graph);

//temp.nodes.push({"id":"Cheese", "radius":20});

//localStorage.graph = JSON.stringify(temp);

console.log("2x");
```

HTML

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}
<link href="/css/geico-design-kit.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="~/js/geico-design-kit.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/d3.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/site.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<style>
    .link line {
        stroke: #888;
    }

    text {
        pointer-events: none;
        font: 10px sans-serif;
    }
</style>


<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <h2>Quick Links</h2>
        <ul class="list list--unordered">
            <li>Example Quick Links Here</li>
            <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<button onclick="updateR()" type="button" style="background-color:red">DO NOT PRESS!</button>

<svg id="container" width="960" height="600" style="border:1px solid black;"></svg>
<form id="nodes"></form>
```

Comment: The code you posted has two `console.log("2x");`. One at the top, and one at the bottom.

Comment: Yes, this results in 4 prints, sorry for not being clear on that, I was testing it placing in multiple areas.

Comment: I can't reproduce this — your code is just giving me to `2x` logs. The urls suggests that perhaps there is something redirecting the page from `site.js` to `site.js?v=foo`. Do you see something like that going on the browser's developer tools?

Comment: Can you record you network your network log and see if your browser is making 2 instead of 1? It would be the red button under the `Network` tab in chrome dev tools.

Comment: Yes that is happening based on the logs and it's also showing it loading in the network section of the Chrome console, but I have no idea why there is a second file being loaded/run or where it's coming from.

Comment: As this appears an ASP.NET view, can you check layout file ?

Comment: I am only seeing two "2x" logs when I run your code in Codepen.io and watch the Chrome JS console.

Comment: @CharmisVarghese that was the problem, it was being included twice since it was also in the Layout file causing everything to run twice. Thanks for the help. If you post it as the answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this ASP.NET view is using a layout view and the same file is referenced in that layout file, the rendered output would have multiple references.